# Oracle Equivalent of MySQL's TEXT type

Tags: php, oracle, text, types

Does Oracle have an equivalent column type to MySQL's `TEXT` type?

If not, how are larger blobs of text typically stored? `BLOB`, `varchar(32767)`? It's Oracle 10 being accessed via PHP, if it matters. Historical context is more than welcome.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Oracle has BLOB, CLOB and NCLOB for storing binary, character and unicode character data types. You can also specify the LOB storage area which allows a DBA to fine tune the storage if necessary (i.e. putting the LOB data on separate disks)

This page gives a bit more info:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_blob.htm

Comment: The official docs: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i3237

Answer (score 9):

I think you probably want the [CLOB](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#sthref152) datatype.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle SQL has a limit of 4000 characters for a VARCHAR2 column (Oracle PL/SQL has a higher limit of 32,767 characters). As stated by the others, CLOB is suitable for storing large quantities of text.

Answer (score 2):

The Character Large Object (CLOB) is likely what you are looking for.  However, if you know that all of the text will fit in a VARCHAR2 then definitely put it there.  A clob cannot be used in a group by clause and is much slower to use than a varchar2 in most cases.  If you know that you will exceed the 4000 byte limit, then use the CLOB (which can handle up to 4gb).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `CLOB`. It stands for **Character Large Object**.

A CLOB is used to store unicode character-based data, such as large documents in any character set.

It`s value can be up to **2,147,483,647** characters long.