# Is it possible to insert fingerprint in php having oracle sql developer?

Tags: php, oracle

```
<?php

   include '../conexao_oracle.php';

   $db = $pdo;
   $db->beginTransaction(); // Essential!
   $mimetype = 'image/jpeg';
   $funcionario_id = 10;
   $stmt = $db->prepare(
       "INSERT INTO foto (mimetype, binario, funcionario_id) ".
       "VALUES (:mimetype, EMPTY_BLOB(), :funcionario_id) ".
       "RETURNING binario INTO :binario");
   $stmt->bindParam(':mimetype', $mimetype);
   $stmt->bindParam(':binario', $blob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
   $stmt->bindParam(':funcionario_id', $funcionario_id);
   $blob = fopen('fotos/10.jpg', 'rb');
   $stmt->execute();
   $pdo->commit();
```

we save image through this this in blob if it is possible to store fingerprint in database then what is the best solution for this?

Comment: What format is the fingerprint data in?

Comment: IN BLOB DATATYPE

Comment: I think it's more a case of how do you capture the fingerprint data?

Comment: If it's binary data to be stored in a blob, then the process ought to be pretty much the same as storing an image (which is also binary data) in a blob.

Comment: Thats what i am thinking can php has an capability r any functions to store fingerprint by using blob

Comment: Well it already has the capability to store the image. So it shouldn't be any different - that was my point. Have you actually tried anything? Are you experiencing a specific problem in your code? On stackoverflow we much prefer a concrete problem to a bunch of speculation

Comment: Yes  i am trying to make a query after that i used it in api then i will tell you ts working or not

Comment: Database stores a data in some predefined formats (datatypes). It doesn't take care of its semantic: be it a "fingerprint" (what is it?), an image, a date, some text or anything else - it doesn't matter. So the question is unclear

Comment: You still also didn't answer the question - what format is the fingerprint in? I don't mean where you intend to store it in the database, I mean what is the file / data format of it _before_ you insert it? As we said it _probably_ doesn't matter, if you're just going to put it into a binary blob, but it would clarify things if you mentioned it

Comment: the data is in string

Comment: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPwAAAFECAIAAACMJ8ScAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAIPnSURBVHhe7dxtmSVJsBzoZSAIgiAIC0EQBGEhLARBEARBWAiCIAiCcPc9x7JtvCMys05VV/f0TJf9iMfTw938M7NOz/34v/7jC1/4w/C19F/44/C19F/44/C19F/44/C19C/h//yf//O//tf/+v+eIHg8Lr5dVXlqeaosertffeFn4GvpX8L//t//+3/8j//x/z5B8Hhc/Md/2NT/54ms7P/8n//zv/23//Z/P3GjPJyfG99bJ7l7T2AZhmqE7uMXPoavpX8J2b/TT7VHy/pf/+t/dWUjvRX/+T//5//rCXscewb/6T/9pyj/y3/5L16bMsxbJ57sPeRlAPbPyP9fXjznksObYPz1thRfS/+jyHb+9//+37OI/WxDPuqW

Comment: And where does that string originate from? It looks like it's probably binary, or just possibly base64

Comment: its BASE 64, converted form of fingerprint in base64

Comment: So if it's base64 then it's a string, you can just store it in a text field, no need for blob

Comment: it show more than 12000 character which datatype i used

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180204/oracle-equivalent-of-mysqls-text-type might help. Seems like CLOB is probably what you need.